# Laravel Spatie Multi tenancy can not access authorised routes

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

Im trying to implement laravel multi tenancy using spatie multi tenancy package (https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/introduction). Iam able log into corresponding tenant database by passing database as parameter for login, after successful login the routes inside auth:sanctum can not be accessed as first call is made to PersonalAccessModel and can not determine which database to query. I have tried to set current tenant in log in method but after login and when i enter auth:sanctum routes , current tenant get vanished.

I have tried overriding PersonalAccesstoken model and set database connection dynamically by accessing db name from cache, But soon cache mechanism became a head ache and all i need is to get database name of current tenant in PersonalAccessToken Model